# Lex : line with one character but spaces

Tags: line, lex

I have sentences like :

```
"      a"
"a    "
"      a         "
```

I would like to catch all this examples (with lex), but I don't how to say the beginning of the line

Comment: Can you please show what you have now and talk a little about what you expected it to do?  I'm not sure what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to pull the "a" out as the token, but you don't want to grab any of the whitespace? If this is the case, then you just need something like the following:

```
[\n\t\r ]+ {
  // do nothing
}

"a" {
  assignYYText( yylval );
  return aToken;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure what exactly you're looking for, but the regex symbol to specify matching the beginning of a line in a lex definition is the caret:

```
^
```